# how to redefine \begin{align*} ... \end{align*} to \begin{eqnarray*} .... \end{eqnarray*}

Tags: macros, environments, tex4ht

Scientific word insists in generating displayed math using

```
\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}
```

and htlatex has a bug in that it does not generate bit mapped images in this case.

The fix that I found after trial and error is to replace the above with

```
  \begin{eqnarray*} ....  \end{eqnarray*}
```

So I just need to know what the syntax is supposed to be. The bug that describes this more is here http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?179

Comment: Is it possible to show how are you trying to redefine, the new environment?

Comment: `eqnarray` is deprecated and should not be used any more as it produces inconsistent spacing. If you still want to do it (I'm not familiar with htlatex), you will need to take care of the special issues of starred and no starred form and probably use `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package. Also you should put your actual question into the body and reduce the title.

Comment: @Thanos, I tried silly things, since I do not know the syntax. I looked at many sites, and confused about if I should use \renewcommand or \newcommand or \let or \newenvironemnt or \renewenvironment etc... showing my attempts will make people laugh and will not add much value. I simply do not know the syntax.

Comment: @canaaerus, yes, I have to use it. htlatex has a bug, and does not work with `align*`. I can't change SW to make it not produce this code. So I need a macro or some latex trick to put in preamble to redefine this environment. This is a known bug that I found 3 years ago and is still not fixed in htlatex. thanks.

Comment: I guess the first thing to do would be file a bug report with the official maintainer: http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/projects/tex4ht/

Comment: `\renewenvironment{align*}{\begin{eqnarray*}}{\end{eqnarray*}}` if you keep all the above warnings in mind. And you must promise never to use it with `pdflatex`. `:-)`

Comment: @canaaerus, I could not find a bug reporting web site for htlatex. In addition, this issue was known by the tex4ht folks at one time as I've seen a reference to my page there one time, any way, I will try to send an email to the mailing list for tex4ht again to 'remind' who ever will listen about this.

Comment: The bug tracker is at http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?group=tex4ht

Comment: @T.Verron, thanks. But I get this error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{eqnarray*} on input line 78 ended by \end{align*}` I posted above small example with your command, just in case you think I made an error myself.

Comment: @canaaerus when I saw that last time, the submit button was crossed out and disabled. now when I did click on it again, I see that it says one has to register to submit a bug. I will go ahead and register there now and add this bug.

Comment: @canaaerus, I am trying to register at that web site, but I am getting scary looking warning message "this connection is not trusted" from https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/account/register.php

Comment: I'm getting the same too, but I guess the site it trustworthy and you can just accept their certificate.

Comment: @Nasser As tex4ht hooks into `\begin{document}`, put your redefinition statement after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @T.Verron, please post this as an answer so I can accept it and close this as issue is resolved now. thanks.

Comment: That was far from being a complete answer. I'd say the appropriate answer to this is either that you move all the "solution bits" from your question to an answer (if you have enough rep) and you edit the question title to make it clearer what was the problem, or that this question is closed as too localized.

Comment: @T.Verron, ok thanks for the suggestion. I've added an answer with the resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to CV Radhakrishnan from tex4ht, the bug has been fixed.

There is an option now to handle the problem with images for math in the `align` environment. The option is `pic-align`

```
  htlatex  foo.tex  "html,pic-align"
```

Here is the result now using this option

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}%

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  v^{2} & =& \left(  \dot{x}+v_{x}\right)  ^{2}+v_{y}^{2}\\
        & =& \dot{x}^{2}+l^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2}+2\dot{x}l\dot{\theta}\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{align*}
  v^{2} & =\left(  \dot{x}+v_{x}\right)  ^{2}+v_{y}^{2}\\
        & =\dot{x}^{2}+l^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2}+2\dot{x}l\dot{\theta}\cos\theta
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output from `htlatex foo.tex "html,pic-align"`

[image]

We can see that align now works fine in htlatex !

Just for completion, if someone is using htlatex, you'd need to also add these 2 lines to your config file to force some of the inlined math to be bit mapped. An example `myconfig.cfg`

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}
  \Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
  \Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{ class="math" align="absmiddle"} 
\EndPreamble
```

and now the command is:

```
htlatex foo.tex "myconfig.cfg,html,pic-align"
```